# The code stops after one input

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have to create a program that breaks after the sum of the digits of a number is bigger than 20.(The code seems to break after one entry(i entered the number 5))This is my attempt:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        while (sum < 20)
        {
            string number = Console.In.ReadLine();
            foreach (int num in number)
            {
                sum += num;
            }
            if (sum >= 20)
            {
                break;
            }
            sum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `break;` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code in English. This website is English and names matter. So make it easy for us to help you and don't post in -Spanish-**Portuguese**

Comment: was where the continue is i was trying to test why it was breaking after one attempt

Comment: its portuguese, will edit now

Comment: Also please at least tell us what the result is. Just make it as easy as possible for people to help you. This increases your chances of anyone helping you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no sense however the issue is the ascii value instead of int indicated below:

```
string numero = Console.In.ReadLine();
foreach (int num in numero) ----> This takes ascii value of the char NOT int value
```

Try this code out:

```
public static int CharToInt(char input)
{
    int result = -1;

    if (input >= 48 && input <= 57)
    {
        result = input - '0';
    }

    return result;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int soma = 0;
    while (soma < 20)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Soma is:" + soma);
        string numero = Console.In.ReadLine();
        foreach (char num in numero)
        {
            int value = CharToInt(num);
            soma += value;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Final Soma is:" + soma);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the string number to an integer first with Int.TryParse().

Answer (score 0):

I'd go this way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        string number = Console.In.ReadLine();
        foreach (var num in number.Select(digit => int.Parse(digit.ToString())))
        {
            sum += num;
            if (sum >= 20)
                break; 
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Sum :{0}",sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```